# Sass --watch keeps compiling the file

Tags: sass

I've been unable to find something similar to this on a Google search, but using VSCode and Dart Sass (now v 1.23.1) and running `sass --watch css` the file keeps on saving/compiling

There seemed to be no issue earlier today. However, the version I was running was 1.21. (I updated Sass to use the new module spec)

What is happening?
The file main.scss is saved
Terminal displays Compiled css/main.scss to css/main.css

It then loops, printing the following
Compiled css/main.css to css/main.css

Things I have tried
Uninstalled and reinstalled sass
deleted map files and related compiled files

Aprart from that, I am at a loss of what to try next. Has anyone experienced similar to this and what did they do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this has been reported as a bug](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/853) in the Dart-Sass repository and a pull request has been opened.